# Create a file at container launch in aws fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, devops, aws-fargate

This is the first time i'm using fargate and docker, i know fargate is using docker api to run, so i'm trying to launch a container based on an image that needs some files to be avialable inside the container when it launches, along with some env variables, the problem is that the command and entrypoint is consfusing me and whatever i try, it just won't create these files, the command i'm trying to run is :

echo "some text here" >> /path/to/file/file

How can i do this in command or entrypoint in the fargate console ?

Thank you,

Comment: what kind of file that you trying to create. whats the scenario

Comment: I was given an image that requires some certificates to run with, this image used to run on docker and it simply took the certs from the volume attached to it, i couldn't find a way to attach a volume in fargate without running x2large instances, so i just wanted to create them myself on start.

Comment: As already suggested, if you could build a new image on top of the existing one, you can accept certificate private key as an argument or environment variables

Comment: Yes, but i want to leave that as a last resort xD, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform any operations such as the creation of mandatory files you would generally include these within the [DockerFile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) that then becomes a Docker image.

You generally don't want to update the command/entry point settings in the Task definitions as this will override the behaviour of the container and may lead to the expected behaviour being cancelled.

If some file need to exist within the Docker Container there are a couple of suggestions I would go with:

- Create a [EFS mount](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) and [use it within your containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_EFSVolumeConfiguration.html). These files will then always exist for all containers, this will allow the container to launch without additional tasks.
- If it must be available ahead of the container launch you could create a new Docker image and deploy to [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/) containing your additional changes.
- If it does not need to create ahead of the application then it could be created by the application on the launch.

Regarding environment variables there are 2 options both officially supported within ECS, the first is the [environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html) attribute. This should be used for non sensitive information.

The second option is the [secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html) attribute that will load a secret from either Secrets Manager or SSM Parameter Store.

These will be available to the containers on launch.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for commenting, i tried the efs solution but it requires x2large instances to upload files which doesn't make any sense, or is it not ?

Comment: EFS is not bound to only higher class instances, in fact it can run with Lambdas too. Where did you see this requirement? :)

Comment: I might have understood wrong, but, they said datasync is the best option to upload files to efs, and this is the requirement for the datasync.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/agent-requirements.html

Comment: Ah, this is more targeting for a file storage migration where you would have terabytes of files to move. For creating a single new file you definitely don't need this :)

Comment: I see, i will then retry using the efs service, thank you for the help, i will accept your answer.

Comment: No problem glad I could help, let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: Hi again,
I have another problem, i would really appreciate it if you could help me,
https://serverfault.com/questions/1031245/how-to-assign-which-user-to-execute-commands-isnide-teh-container-in-aws-fargate